# Convert QString to Hex?

Tags: c++, qt, hex, ascii, qstring

I have a QString where I append data input from the user.

At the end of the QString, I need to append the hexadecimal representation of a "Normal" QString.

For example:

```
QString Test("ff00112233440a0a");
QString Input("Words");

Test.append(Input);//but here is where Input needs to be the Hex representation of "Words"

//The resulting variable should be
//Test == "ff00112233440a0a576f726473";
```

How can I convert from ASCII (I think) to it's Hex representation?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were very close:

`Test.append(QString::fromLatin1(Input.toLatin1().toHex()));`

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: The output when trying to input the QString "Test1" is "30303035"

Comment: Maybe your version of Qt is different from mine. I'm using 5.2.1. I updated the answer to make it a little less ambiguous by explicitly converting the `QByteArray` to `QString` using the `QString::fromLatin1` function. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Here's what I tested: `QString Test("ff00112233440a0a"); QString Input("Test1"); Test.append(QString::fromLatin1(Input.toLatin1().toHex())); qDebug() << Test;`. And here's what I got: `ff00112233440a0a5465737431`. If you're using Qt4, you can try `toAscii` and `fromAscii` instead of Latin1.

Comment: Perhaps I have a bug in my code elsewhere. Let me check

Comment: Ah. Yes I figured it out. I was testing it with the wrong variable. My mistake. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to your problem.

Given a character, you can use the following simple function to compute its hex representation.

```
// Call this function twice -- once with the first 4 bits and once for the last
// 4 bits of a char to get the hex representation of a char.
char toHex(char c) {
   // Assume that the input is going to be 0-F.
   if ( c <= 9 ) {
      return c + '0';
   } else {
      return c + 'A' - 10;
   }
}
```

You can use it as:

```
char c;
// ... Assign a value to c

// Get the hex characters for c
char h1 =  toHex(c >> 4);
char h2 = toHex(c & 0xF);
```

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. The input is not from 0-F. It is just a normal word... like "pie" would be "706965" in Hex